# MOSFET power supply ON with no MCU input

Tags: transistors, led, mosfet

I have a MOSFET circuit that a microcontroller manipulates (using its GPIOs) to control power to other devices.  I noticed yesterday when I detached the microcontroller from the circuit the LED on the board was still lit up.  So this means that 5V on the MOSFET's supply was making it to the drain and hence the R_load.  Below is the schematic for the circuit.  Is this failure by design or some other failure going on?

When should I expect 5V supplied to the R_load (GPIO: 3.3V, GND, open circuit)?

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a P-Type MOSFET.  It conducts when its gate is pulled low.  That's why it has the pull up on its gate - it is off as long as the gate is high.

Your 2N3904 pulls the MOSFET gate down when you supply current to its base - when the GPIO is high, the collector goes low and the MOSFET provides power to your load.

The effect you saw occurred when there was no processor installed on the board.

The 2N3904 has fairly high gain - a very small current at the base could cause it to pull the gate down enough to power the load.

You need to do this to the base of your 2N3904:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpHKRp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That will pull the base of the the 2N3904 low when there's no other connected input.  R2 provides a better path to ground for stray voltages than the base, making sure that the transistor stays off until you want it on.

Make sure that R2 is larger than R1.

There are pre-biased transistors that have the resistors built in.  They are a drop in replacement for many SMD transistors.  Swap your 2N3904 for prebiased NPN transisor.  Problem solved.

---

I went and ran it through a simulator.  The circuit works as described:  High on the base of the 2N3904 turns on power to the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHLgMo.png)</sup>

You are either getting way too much current creeping in somewhere, or else something is broken.  Maybe there's some other part of the circuit pulling up the base of the 2N3904.

Ground the base completely (short to ground) and see if the LED still lights up.

Comment: Hmm I just soldered in a 10k resistor as specified and the LED is still on although no MCU is attached

Comment: Hmm indeed. I'll fire up a simulator here in a minute and have a look.

Comment: In the mean time, try a 1k from base to ground.

Comment: Maybe also make R10 smaller.

Comment: How much current do you get through the load?

Comment: I soldered one end of a through hole 10K resistor to the SMD 1K resistor pad opposite to the GPIO output and the other end of the through hole resistor was connected to ground.

Comment: just tried a 2k from base to ground, no luck.  I can try 330 for R10?

Comment: 330 for R10 should be safe.

Comment: looks like I made a mistake when I reconstructed your suggestion. I did not notice the 1k resistor was between the GPIO and transistor. Let me reconstruct this on a breadboard quickly

Comment: you are correct.  I recontructed the circuit you suggested on the breadboard and MOSFET was off when MCU was disconnected and GPIO grounded and the MOSFET was conducting/ON when GPIO is at 3.3V

Answer (score 1):

It should be off for input low and on for high. For open it will likely be off unless there is some kind of antenna effect on the base connection to the BJT.

You might want to use a faster diode than the 1N4007, such as 1N5819.